# similar to docutils in PHP

Tags: php, python, documentation

Just curious to know is there any document utility available in PHP which can perform something like docutils in python ?

A libary which can be very user friendly in terms of converting restructured text into HTML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpDocumentor is quite outdated. Have a look at [DocBlox (Github Repository)](https://github.com/mvriel/Docblox) or [DocBlox-project.org](http://www.docblox-project.org/)

edit:
docblox merged with phpdocumentor and they now maintain phpdocumentor 2.
links that take you directly to the project:
[phpdoc.org](http://www.phpdoc.org/)
[github repo](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2)

Comment: link is down or moved to some other location :(

Comment: Works fine for me and its a usual link to a github repository :?

Comment: aah..opens with FF, IE but not in chrome in my case

Answer (score 1):

Try [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).